# Train-test split within modeling function

Tags: machine-learning, modeling, data-transformation, dataset, train-test-split

I have this function I wrote:

```
def singleModelCV(data, target, model):
    features = data.drop(columns=target)
    target = data[target]

    state = 42
    X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(features, target, test_size = 0.2, 
    random_state = state)

    k_fold = KFold(n_splits=10)
    score = np.mean(cross_val_score(model, X_train, Y_train, scoring='r2', cv=k_fold))

    return(score)
```

My question is: is it a bad practice to include the splitting of the data within the function that also trains the model and returns the final scores?

I'm doing this because throughout my project I will alter the dataset through feature transformation, feature engineering, etc, in an iterative manner, and I want to compare the scores to the previous ones to see how each technique influences the models. That is why I have one method that would return that both splits the data and trains the model as I would pass the new transformed datasets through this method. I am also aware of pipelines and will implement this to make the workflow cleaner and prevent any data leakage from standardization.

If someone could clarify this for me it would be greatly appreaciated. Also any suggestions on how I could carry this task out in an efficient manner would also be fantastic. Thanks!

Comment: Shouldn't you compare models on your test set?

Comment: I don't agree with @gunes that you should use the test set for model building and selection. However, by default [KFold](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.KFold.html) doesn't shuffle the data. Is that what you intend?

Comment: Hey @dipetkov, that's good point; but I didn't say we should do model selection using the test set. Rather, it was intended for final comparison for reporting. The OP doesn't use the test at all in his/her setup, which makes me doubt what he's trying to do.

Comment: @gunes True. Perhaps we should ask the OP: > Do you call your "validation" set the "test" set? In other words, have you set aside a part of the data for the final evaluation of the "best" model?

Comment: I believed that the cross-validation method was intended so that a validation set was not necessary, especially if you are working with a small dataset such as the Boston housing dataset that I'm working with.

Comment: I also just realised that I was misunderstood something. You do not need to split the dataset into training and test sets before using the cross_val_score function. Just pass in the features and the target variable and the function automatically creates the sets at each fold.